# How to define default values for SAP Hana sqlscript input parameter?

Tags: sql, parameters, hana

I am creating a set of SQLscripts for SAP Hana administration. In most cases the scripts are run with same parameters but sometimes it would be handy to customize them without re-writing.

That's why I would like to have default value for script parameters. Here is the solution I created:

```
WITH BASIS_INFO AS
  (SELECT
    CASE SUBSTR('&1',1,1) WHEN '&' THEN '%' ELSE '&1' END "SECT"
  FROM DUMMY )
SELECT 
  HOST, PORT, SECTION, KEY, VALUE 
from
  BASIS_INFO BI,
  M_CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES CF
WHERE CF.SECTION like BI.SECT;
```

Does anybody know about a more elegant solution?

Regards,
Darvud